# Jest test fail even the returned array values are correct

Tags: node.js, arrays, typescript, testing, ts-jest

the expect returned values are the same but to test always fail, here the logged result

```
Error: expect(received).toContain(expected) // indexOf

Expected value: [72, 71]
Received array: [72, 71]
```

[image]

I will be gratefull for any explanation

Answer (score 1):

In fact I just found a quick solution using a correct [jest matcher](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectarraycontainingarray)

**Before**

```
expect(c.users.map((u) => u.id)).toContain([72, 71]);
```

**After**

```
 expect(c.users.map((u) => u.id)).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining([72, 71]));
```

Comment: This is working as expected, by the way. `toContain` takes only single item. In this case, the single item is the entire array `[72, 71]`. That array is not an element of the array `[72, 71]`. The matcher would pass if your received array was instead `[[72, 71]]`.